# How do I create a message box for Xamarin Forms ListView?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

The question is simple. I Need to have an message box for the cells in a listview app that was created. However I failed, because the one time I did it, it was in a not XamarinForms App. Now I don't know how to create a message box that responds to each cell.

Code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace IconsApp
{
public partial class ListViewPage : ContentPage
{
    public ListViewPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainListView.ItemsSource = new List<Element>
        {
            new Element {new Title = "ok", Description= "ok"},new Element {Title = "ok", Description = "ok"},
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MainListView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => { 
  var item = (Element) e.SelectedItem;
  DisplayAlert(item.Title,item.Description,"OK");
};
```

Comment: in the code where you setup your ListView - in your case, in the constructor